# Contingency table once against multiple table

Tags: r, contingency

I have a table like the following:

```
V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10
fve fve fve fve fve fve fve fve mdm mdm
mdm fve fve fve fve fve fve fve fve fve
fve fve fve fve fve fve fve fve fve fve
mdm fve fve fve fve fve fve fve fve fve
fve fve fve fve fve fve fve fve fve fve
```

and I would like to count the frequence from column 1 against all and get something like this:

```
    fve mdm
fve 25  2
mdm 18  0
```

Is it possible to do it ? I tried with `table()` and `ftable()` but output is not corresponding to what I'm expecting.

Comment: `table(unlist(df1[-1]))` gets the output

Comment: Please explain how you got the numbers in your results from your original table.

Comment: example line 1: fve fve fve fve fve fve fve fve mdm mdm you have 2 variable fve and mdm. The references is column one so you have : fve vs fve = 7 and fve vs mdm = 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly different option is

```
table(df1[,1][row(df1[-1])], unlist(df1[-1])) 
#     fve mdm
# fve  25   2
# mdm  18   0
```

Answer (score 3):

For the modified question:

```
> tapply(unlist(dat[-1]), rep(dat[[1]], length(dat[-1])), table)
$fve

fve mdm 
 25   2 

$mdm

fve mdm 
 18   0
```

I suppose you could run `do.call(rbind, ...)`  on those values to get the desired table:

Comment: This will wrapp the columns. It's not exactly what I mean. Please the edition of my question.

Comment: You should always provide a data object that has the needed complexity for testing.